# How can I start over from WordPress locally in WAMP Server?

Tags: wamp, wordpress

I'm studying WordPress and doing some experimentations, manipulations with adding pages, editing, etc.

First, I installed WAMP Server 2.4, then install WordPress by extracting then moving its folder inside `C:/Wamp/www` folder. Then I do some manipulations, editing, testing by going to `localhost/mywebsite/wp-admin`.

My question is, how do I start over from the very start? I want to delete what I have done, starting over from scratch, delete my modifications, the pages I added, the edits I did, everything?

Does deleting WordPress folder inside `C:/Wamp/www` folder, and copying a new fresh files will do it? Or is it the database which I need to delete?

Also, how to do this in my GoDaddy Linux hosting account? Do I just need to *uninstall* the WordPress attached to a specific domain name, then *reinstall* it again to that same domain name?

Answer (score 1):

Just reverting the files themselves won't do it. WordPress stores most of the information (i.e. all pages, content, etc.) in the database. The files in your `www` directory themselves are mostly the WordPress core system, plugins, and the themes.

So before you decide to make any major changes, you need to make a backup of your existing database *and* the files to revert to if you want to go back.* If you have phpMyAdmin running, this is quite easy to do by exporting the entire database. For the files, a simple ZIP or Tarball will do. When you want to go back, overwrite the files and import the SQL data again.**

The process is the same for your web host – you absolutely need a database backup *and* the files. Don't mix them up though, there might be dependencies.

<sub>* You could also put your WordPress files under [version control](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) (e.g. with Git or SVN) and do your changes in a separate branch.</sub>
<sub>** When you export, make sure that you check *Drop Tables* to clear the data upon reimporting.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of replacing files. When I want to reset, I just change the database prefix in [`wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php). This will prompt a new install.

```
$table_prefix = 'wp2_';
```

This way, the first install with prefix `'wp_'` <sup>`*`</sup> remains in the database and we can even switch back to it simply changing the prefix. So, in the same database we'll have different prefixed tables that belong to different installations. Keep an eye in PHPMyAdmin to see what's happening.

<sup>`*` On live servers, for security reasons, it's recommended to use hard-to-guess prefixes, like `'w3p_v1_'`.</sup>

All themes and plugins installed remain available inside the folder `wp-content/`.
And it may be a good idea to rename the folder `wp-content/uploads/` to `uploads-1/` and create a new, empty, uploads folder. Doing so, each test site keeps its uploaded files separated. But if we are into heavy testing, it really doesn't matter if the uploads folder gets all messed up. Each installation has the correct files assigned in its database tables.

Note that what constitutes [our data](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups) in a WordPress installation are:

- the database tables
- the file `wp-config.php`
- the folder `wp-content/`

If we add custom settings in the root file [`.htaccess`](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), then it should be added to the list above.